# Enabled/Disabled preference listener

Tags: android, android-layout, android-preferences, android-sharedpreferences

I have a custom `Preference B` that is dependent on a SwitchPreference `Preference A`. Is there a way for `Preference B` to listen to the enable/disable of the switch that it depends on?

The closest listener I can find is `OnPreferenceChangedListener` but this of course is for the actual change of the preference value, not the state.

Answer (score 0):

You can put into `Application` class as static variable.